# Methods for Numerical Integration of a Definite Integral over Singularities

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, quadrature

In studying the Schwarz-Christoffel mapping, I have come across certain integrals that I want to numerically integrate. For example, one such integral is:

$\int_{0}^{1} (z^2 - z)^{-2/3} dz$

A cursory look at a graph of the integrand by Desmos shows this:
[image]

The integral is symmetric about $x = 1/2$; however, it has singularities at both endpoints. Moreover, on a glance it seems that these endpoints will allow the integral to converge.

However, upon evaluation of the definite integral using different programs like Wolfram-Alpha, I get answers which are imaginary, which could not be the case since the integral is on the real line. Wolfram-Alpha gives $-2.64996 - 4.58986 i$. I assume it is because the roots that are evaluated using these programs are not the real roots.

Is there a way for me to transform the integral for the singularities to disappear? I attempted shifting the curve so that the singularities lie at $x = -1/2$ and $x = 1/2$. However, I realize that the problem with integration over the endpoints still exist. I planned on using quadrature algorithms such as Gaussian and Clenshaw-Curtis to carry out the numerical integration. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Split the computation in the middle at $1/2$ and use partial integration to remove the singularity.
$$
\int_0^{1/2}(z-z^2)^{-2/3}dz = \Bigl[3z^{1/3}(1-z)^{-2/3}\Bigr]_0^{1/2}+2\int_0^{1/2}z^{1/3}(1-z)^{-5/3}dz
$$
The first term has a finite value, and the second has a continuous and bounded integrand, so that standard numerical methods should give a reliable result.

---

You should get real results from WA if you make the radicant positive, that is, replace $(z^2-z)^{-2/3}$ with $-(z-z^2)^{-2/3}$. (The graph is wrong in that light, values should be negative.) Remember that CAS are aware of complex numbers and will always use the main branch of the root, $w^a$ evaluates to $\exp(a\,{\rm Ln}(w))=\exp(a\ln|w|+i\,a\arg(w))$. In this case this leads to a constant factor $\frac{1+i\sqrt3}2$ relative to the real result, that is the real result is twice the real part of the WA value.

Comment: As a useful note, this trick can be extended to higher dimensions using [Duffy Transform](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0719090)